# How to put the h1 element on the same line as the navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I tried putting it on the same line by using the `float: left` element on the `h1` and `float: right` on the nav, but it keeps putting the `h1` below or above the `nav`. I am trying to set up a website so that the top line can read the name of the company and the links to the different pages through the navigation bar. Is there something to do with it? Here is some of my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Virginia Delights</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="Delights.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">

<header>
<nav>

    <a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp;
    <a href="about.html">About</a> &nbsp;
    <a href="mission.html">Mission</a> &nbsp;
    <a href="staff.html">Staff</a> &nbsp;
    <a href="donate.html">Donate</a> &nbsp;
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>


</nav>

<h1>Virginia Delights</h1>
</header>


<img class="rounding" src="Virginia Delights Logo.jpg" alt="Logo" height="200" width="200"> 



<footer>

Copyright &copy; 2020 Virginia Delight
</footer>

    </div>


</body>

</html>



nav { text-align:right;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    font-size:1.3em;
    text-shadow:3px 3px 3px gray;}

header {width: 100%;}

nav a {text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
}


h1 {float: left;
     height: 100px;
     width: 700px;
     font-size: 2em;
     padding-left:150px;
     padding-right:150px;
     border-radius:20px;
     padding-top:0.5px;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     text-shadow:3px 3px 3px gray;
     color:white;}
```

Comment: Hi, @CollegeStruggles have you tried by using [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Flexbox)?It's not aligning because `<nav>` tag is considered an separate element from `<h1>` so it's taking the entire line. The browser basically adds a line to each one of them

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear where you want your logo image, but all in all you can use `display: flex;` on the container (`header`)  and add `justify-content: space-between`, plus the settings used below.

Note: I changed some of your width settings to fit everything in to one line in the snippet here, I erased the `float` settings, and I changed the order of elements in the HTML code because that really didn't seem logical in your code, considering the way you want it to appear.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
}

nav {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px gray;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-top: 0.5px;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px gray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <img class="rounding" src="Virginia Delights Logo.jpg" alt="Logo" height="100" width="100"> 
    <h1>Virginia Delights</h1>
    <nav>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp;
      <a href="about.html">About</a> &nbsp;
      <a href="mission.html">Mission</a> &nbsp;
      <a href="staff.html">Staff</a> &nbsp;
      <a href="donate.html">Donate</a> &nbsp;
      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <footer>
    Copyright &copy; 2020 Virginia Delight
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can't really tell until you show us your css, otherwise here is some good old fashion css and html I would do with your html.

Remember you want to make everything semantic so I would recommend making your navbar like this

```
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <h1 id="logo">Virginia Delight</h1>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="staff.html">Staff</a></li>
                        <li><a href="mission.html">Mission</a></li>
                        <li><a href="staff.html">Staff</a></li>
                        <li><a href="donate.html">Donate</a></li>
                        </li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
```

As for the CSS you just need to float the id="logo" to the left and the nav to the right

```
header {
    background-color: <Whatever color>;
    min-height: 100px;
    color: <Whatever color>;
}

header #logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

header nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

header li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-left:30px;
}

header a {
text-decoration: none;
color: <Whatever color>;
}
```